# SQL Query :Is it possible to count / group based on date with a sum over the group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following question: 
To determine the progress of a production process the following records are stored:

```
+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
| Order | Date                    | Count | State |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
| X     | 2018-02-10 00:00:00.000 | 10    | 0     |
| X     | 2018-02-11 00:00:00.000 | 4     | 1     |
| X     | 2018-02-12 00:00:00.000 | 2     | 2     |
| X     | 2018-02-13 00:00:00.000 | 3     | 1     |
| X     | 2018-02-14 00:00:00.000 | 1     | 3     |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
```

The result of the query should be:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Order | Count | State |
+-------+-------+-------+
| X     | 3     | 0     |
| X     | 5     | 1     |
| X     | 1     | 2     |
| X     | 1     | 3     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

- 10 items are initially booked on state 0
- On 2018-02-11 4 items are progressed to state 1, resulting in 6 remaining items on state 0 and 4 items on state 1.
- On 2018-02-12 2 items are progressed from state 1 to state 2, resulting in 6 items on state 0, 2 items on state 1 and 2 items on state 2.
- On 2018-02-13 3 items are progressed from state 0 to state 1, resulting in 3 items remaining on state 0, 5 items on state 1 and 2 items on state 2.
- On 2018-02-14 1 items progressed from state 2 to 3, resulting in 3 items remaining on state 0, 5 items on state 1 and 1 item on state 2 and 1 item on state 3.

It is not possible to skip a state.

Sample script:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItemState](
    [Gid] uniqueidentifier not null 
            constraint PK_OrderItemState primary key nonclustered
            constraint DC_OrderItemState default newid(),
    [Order] nchar(16) not null,
    [Date] datetime not null,
    [Count] int not null,
    [State] int not null
)
GO

insert into [dbo].[OrderItemState] values (newid(), 'X', '2018-02-10', 10, 0)
insert into [dbo].[OrderItemState] values (newid(), 'X', '2018-02-11', 4, 1)
insert into [dbo].[OrderItemState] values (newid(), 'X', '2018-02-12', 2, 2)
insert into [dbo].[OrderItemState] values (newid(), 'X', '2018-02-13', 3, 1)
insert into [dbo].[OrderItemState] values (newid(), 'X', '2018-02-14', 1, 3)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion window functions will be the cleanest way to accomplish this (you didn't specify your version, so I'm assuming you're using 2012 or later).

```
WITH Progress AS
(
SELECT [Order], State,
  SUM(Count) AS ItemsProgressedToThisState,
  LEAD(SUM(Count), 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY State) AS ItemsProgressedPastThisState
FROM OrderItemState
GROUP BY [Order], State
)
SELECT [Order], State, ItemsProgressedToThisState - ItemsProgressedPastThisState AS [Count]
FROM Progress
ORDER BY [Order], State
```

The CTE isn't really necessary, you can subtract the `SUM` and `LEAD` directly. I just wanted to make the logic clear: count the number of items that have reached the current state, and then subtract the number of items that have reached the next state.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to count all states and subtract them from precedent:

```
SELECT
   [Order]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 0 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_0]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 1 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_1]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 2 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_2]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 3 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_3]
FROM [dbo].[OrderItemState] as ois
GROUP BY [Order]
```

output here:

```
Order   State_0 State_1 State_2 State_3
X       10      7       2       1
```

The rest is just to obtain your output:

```
SELECT 
 [Order]
 ,[Count]
 ,RIGHT([State],1) AS [State]
FROM
(
SELECT
  grp.[Order]
  ,ISNULL(grp.[State_0],0) - ISNULL(grp.[State_1],0) as [State_0]
  ,ISNULL(grp.[State_1],0) - ISNULL(grp.[State_2],0) as [State_1]
  ,ISNULL(grp.[State_2],0) - ISNULL(grp.[State_3],0) as [State_2]
  ,ISNULL(grp.[State_3],0) as [State_3]
FROM
(
SELECT
   [Order]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 0 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_0]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 1 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_1]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 2 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_2]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ois.[State] = 3 THEN ois.[Count] ELSE 0 END) as [State_3]
FROM [dbo].[OrderItemState] as ois
GROUP BY [Order]
) grp
)s
UNPIVOT 
  (
    [Count] FOR [State] IN ([State_0],[State_1],[State_2],[State_3])
  ) AS p


Order   Count   State
X       3       0
X       5       1
X       1       2
X       1       3
```

[dbdiffle here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=912965b0e007d7703057771e19e33d79)

Comment: Nice solution, at this moment this will work for me.
But can it also be done (and how) with a recursive common table expression, so the number of states is not fixed?